# ASP.NET MVC Asyncronous Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asynchronous

I'm trying to follow the example on MSDN.com for Async controllers.  I have some questions.  Here is a link to the write up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28VS.100%29.aspx

And here is the code I'm referring to:

```
public class PortalController : AsyncController {
public void NewsAsync(string city) {

    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    NewsService newsService = new NewsService();
    newsService.GetHeadlinesCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        AsyncManager.Parameters["headlines"] = e.Value;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    };
    newsService.GetHeadlinesAsync(city);
}

public ActionResult NewsCompleted(string[] headlines) {
    return View("News", new ViewStringModel
    {
        NewsHeadlines = headlines
    });
}
}
```

My first question is this:  Do I have to have multiple methods in my service also?  For example I took my method called abc in the controller and created two new methods out of it called abcAsync and abcCompleted.  Do I have to do something similar in my service?  It looks this way according to the example, but the MSDN example does not say anything about modifying my service.

Next question,  what does the syntax of this look like if my service takes multiple parameters?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360), as Microsoft is planning on improving the way they do asynchrony in C# 5.0.  It makes writing asynchronous methods less of a pain, although it is still only a CTP.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to have multiple methods in my service also?

This will depend on what you mean by *service*. For example if you have a web service that you imported using [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) you could specify the `/async` switch which will generate both synchronous and asynchronous method signatures for all methods when generating the proxy. On the service side you don't need to have multiple methods.

> what does the syntax of this look like if my service takes multiple parameters?

If you used `svcutil.exe` to generate the client proxy with the `/async` switch, in the generated client proxy the method signature will match that on the server. So if you have multiple arguments on the server method, you will also have multiple arguments on the client method.